# ask from the command prompt to input data to all the entities, and it should give the option to add more than one entry at a time

Tags: javascript, command-prompt

```
<script>
  class Course {
    constructor(title, stream, type, start_date, end_date) {
      this.title = title;
      this.stream = stream;
      this.type = type;
      this.start_date = start_date;
      this.end_date = end_date;
      }
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  let newCourseInstance = new Course(
    window.prompt("Title:"),
    window.prompt("Stream:"),
    window.prompt("Type:"),
    window.prompt("Start date:"),
    window.prompt("End date:")
    );
```

Hello everyone!! i just want to ask something about an assignment that i should do.  The application must ask from the command prompt to input data to all the entities, and it should give the option to add more than one entry at a time. Do you know how to do this iterration? Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare all the entities you want in an array and iterate this one and pass it to the class constructor.

```
      class Course {
        constructor(title, stream, type, start_date, end_date) {
         this.title = title;
         this.stream = stream;
         this.type = type;
         this.start_date = start_date;
         this.end_date = end_date;
       }
     }   

    const entities = ["Title:","Stream:","Type:","Start date:","End date:"]
    const data = entities.map(d => window.prompt(d))
    let newCourseInstance = new Course(data.join(','));
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! But how can the iteration be if the user wants to do more than one entry in the course? I should ask if user wants to add another course and then continue.